# My program isnt functioning properly

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, class, android-layout

So here's the problem I am trying to make an app for converting measurements and every time i press calculate it just keeps giving me my toast saying "Can't convert to same type" and I am not converting to the same type! I don't know why its doing this! And I have one thing to change meters to centimeters and its supposed to work but when i do that in my spinner it doesn't. I am using android 4.1.2 API 16. Testing on a LG  L9 p769 T-Mobile. also I tried cleaning it an everything nothing works i don't see any errors in my code?

```
spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {

                String selectedItem = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(selectedItem.equals("meter")){
                    d4 = 1;
                }

                if(selectedItem.equals("centimeter")){
                    d4 = 2;
                }

                if(selectedItem.equals("milimeter")){
                    d4 = 3;
                }

                if(selectedItem.equals("yard")){
                    d4 = 4;
                }

                if(selectedItem.equals("foot")){
                    d4 = 5;
                }

                if(selectedItem.equals("inch")){
                    d4 = 6;
                }



            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent) {
                d4 = 99;
            }
        });

        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg2,
                    int pos, long arg4) {

                String selectedItem1 = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(selectedItem1.equals("meter")){
                    d7 = 1;
                }

                if(selectedItem1.equals("centimeter")){
                    d7 = 2;
                }

                if(selectedItem1.equals("milimeter")){
                    d7 = 3;
                }

                if(selectedItem1.equals("yard")){
                    d7 = 4;
                }

                if(selectedItem1.equals("foot")){
                    d7 = 5;
                }

                if(selectedItem1.equals("inch")){
                    d7 = 6;
                }



            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent) {
                d7 = 99;
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.tcMenu:
            Intent e = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(e);
            break;
        case R.id.weightMenu:
            Intent f = new Intent(this, weight.class);
            startActivity(f);
            break;
        case R.id.mikmMenu:
            Intent g = new Intent(this, distance.class);
            startActivity(g);
            break;
        case R.id.measureMenu:
            Intent h = new Intent(this, measurement.class);
            startActivity(h);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }




    public void calCulate(View view){
        String d1, d2;
        Double d5, d6;
        double d3;
        Toast itemdupe = Toast.makeText(measurement.this, "Can't convert to same type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        d1 = et1.getText().toString();
        d5 = Double.parseDouble(d1);

        if(d4 == d7){

            itemdupe.show();

        }

        if((d4 == 1) && (d7 ==2)){
            d3 = d5 / 0.010000;
            et2.setText("" + d3);
        }








    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg2,
                    int pos, long arg4) {

                //Should be spin2 below, not spin1 I believe
                String selectedItem1 = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

You have a lot of code duplication in there...

Comment: lol I am such a idiot it worked I cant believe I didn't see that sorry for wasting your time sir...